# Four different outcomes when overflowing main stack

Tags: memory, stack, rust

Out of curiosity, I was playing with overflowing the the stack with this code:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array: [i32; 3000000000] = [3; 3000000000];
    println!("{}", my_array[0]);
}
```

And to my surprise I ended with three different outcomes:

1) This is what I expected:

```
thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
    Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

2) Surprisingly vague:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

3) Totally puzzling:

```
208333333
```

In order for stochastic nature to show up I had to restart the shell, otherwise results were deterministic ( I would get the same error message over and over).

I compiled with just:

```
rustc my_file.rs
```

and excuted with:

```
./my_file
```

My rustc version:

```
rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)
```

My ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Also the size of the array I am trying to create is 12 gigs, I am on a tiny laptop that does not have that amount of RAM.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Edit:

I was playing with the size of array (which I think might be the reason for different errors, but why?), and got one more:

4) Makes perfect sense.

```
error: the type `[i32; 300000000000000]` is too big for the current architecture
```

and my system architecture is `x86_64`.

Comment: So, you are testing undefined behavior and wondering why you cannot define what you get ;) ?

Comment: Hm, does Rust specify somewhere that this is undefined behavior?

Comment: Undefined behavior should only occur in an `unsafe` block. This behavior looks like a bug.

Comment: @LambdaFairy is right, you should really report this. rust should never run into illegal instructions without unsafe blocks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that above randomness is related to my machine.

I checked the same code on another machine, that has the same `rustc` version, `ubuntu` version and the same architecture. And my results a much more predictable:

If size of the array `536870871` or greater (without getting to case 4) I get:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

If size of array is `536870870` or smaller (without being small enough to actually work) I get:

```
thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Not a single time have I gotten a case `3)` where I had garbage returned.